# Why does n^O(1) mean “polynomial time?”

Tags: math, big-o

An algorithm runs in polynomial time if it's runtime is O(n<sup>k</sup>) for some k. However, I've also seen polynomial time defined as time n<sup>O(1)</sup>.

I have some questions about this:

1. Why is n<sup>O(1)</sup> polynomial time? What happened to k?
2. If n<sup>O(1)</sup> is polynomial time, then 3n<sup>2</sup> should be n<sup>O(1)</sup>. But where did the 3 go? How does that work?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example where your notation with the O in the exponent is used? I see where you're going with it, and it's intuitive that `n^O(1)` would be a polynomial, but I'm not sure if I like this notation. `f(x) = O(g(x))` is already sloppy for `f(x) ∈ O(g(x))`, and using the term as an exponent takes it farther away from its original meaning, and makes it harder for people learning the notation that `O(g(x))` is a set and not a single function. However, if you know what you're doing, this could come in quite handy. :)

Comment: @Carsten- I've seen this used in books on complexity theory (for example, *Computational Complexity* by Arora and Barak). Also, the notation f(n) = O(g(n)) is confusing but not technically an abuse of notation; big-O notation is formally defined this way by many authors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you have an expression like "the runtime is O(n)" or "the runtime is O(n<sup>2</sup>)," the O(n) and O(n<sup>2</sup>) terms aren't actual functions. Instead, they're placeholders for some other function with some property. For example, take this statement:

> The runtime of the algorithm is O(n)

This statement really means

> There is some function f(n) where the runtime of the algorithm is f(n) and f(n) = O(n)

For example, if a function's actual runtime is 137n + 42, the statement "the runtime of the algorithm is O(n)" is true because there is some function (namely, f(n) = 137n + 42) where the runtime of the algorithm is f(n) and f(n) = O(n).

Given this, let's think about what the statement "the runtime of the algorithm is n<sup>O(1)</sup>" means. This statement is equivalent to

> There is some function f(n) where the runtime of the algorithm is n<sup>f(n)</sup> and f(n) = O(1)

Now that we've gotten the terminology clearer, what exactly does this mean? Intuitively, a function is O(1) if it's eventually bounded from above by some constant. Therefore, any function f(n) that's O(1) must satisfy f(n) ≤ k once n gets sufficiently large. Therefore, at least intuitively, n<sup>O(1)</sup> means "n raised to some power that's at most k," which sounds like the definition of a polynomial function.

Of course, there's that pesky issue of constant factors.  The function 137n<sup>3</sup> is definitely O(n<sup>3</sup>), but it has a huge constant term in front. On the other hand, if we have a function of the form n<sup>O(1)</sup>, there isn't a constant term in front of the n<sup>3</sup>. How do we handle this?

This is where we can get cute with the math. In the case of 137n<sup>3</sup>, note that when n > 1, we have

> 137n<sup>3</sup> = n<sup>log<sub>n</sub>137</sup> n<sup>3</sup> = n<sup>3 + log<sub>n</sub> 137</sup>

Notice that this is n raised to the power of log<sub>n</sub> 137. Although it might look like the function log<sub>n</sub> 137 grows as n grows larger, it actually has the opposite behavior: it *decreases* as n grows. The reason for this is that we can use the change of base formula to rewrite log<sub>n</sub> 137 as

> log<sub>n</sub> 137 = log 137 / log n

Which clearly decreases in the long term when log n decreases. Therefore, the expression 3 + log<sub>n</sub>137 ends up being bounded from above by some constant, so it's O(1).

Using this technique, it's possible to convert O(n<sup>k</sup>) to n<sup>O(1)</sup> by choosing the exponent of n to be k plus the log base n of the constant factor in front of the n<sup>k</sup> term that comes up in the big-O notation.  Similarly, we can convert back from n<sup>O(1)</sup> to O(n<sup>k</sup>) by choosing k to be any constant that upper-bounds the function hidden by the O(1) term in the exponent of n.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 137n = n^(log_n137) n^3. maybe, 137n^3 = ..., and not 137n?

Comment: Oh whoops, that's a typo.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: +1 for taking the time to put in all the `<sup>`s and `<sub>`s (although the answer is great too!) :)

Comment: +1. But you've got another typo at "Of course, there's that pesky issue of constant factors. The function 137n^3 is definitely O(n),"