# If a non-deterministic Turing machine runs in f(n) space, then why does it run in 2^O(f(n)) time?

Tags: math, big-o, complexity-theory, turing-machines

Assuming that f(n) >= n.

If possible, I'd like a proof in terms of Turing machines. I understand the reason why with machines that run on binary, because each "tape cell" is a bit with either 0 or 1, but in Turing machines a tape cell could hold any number of symbols. I'm having trouble why the base is '2' and not something like 'b' where 'b' is the number of types of symbols of the Turing machine tape.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a theoretical question not a programming question.

Comment: You should ask this on the computer science stack exchange.

Comment: Also posted at [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/102260/if-a-non-deterministic-turing-machine-runs-in-fn-space-then-why-does-it-run-i). Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, you may flag to request migration. Or you can delete the question on one site and then post to another site.

Answer (score 4):

The important detail here is that the runtime is 2<sup>**O(n)**</sup> rather than **O(2<sup>n</sup>)**. In other words, the runtime is "two raised to the power of something that's O(n)," rather than "something that's on the order of 2<sup>n</sup>." That's a subtle distinction, so let's dissect it a bit.

Let's consider the function 4<sup>n</sup>. This function is not O(2<sup>n</sup>), because 4<sup>n</sup> outgrows 2<sup>n</sup> in the long run. However, notice that 4<sup>n</sup> = 2<sup>2n</sup>, and since 2n = O(n) we can say that 4<sup>n</sup> = 2<sup>O(n)</sup>.

Similarly, take b<sup>n</sup> for any base b. If b > 2, then b<sup>n</sup> is not O(2<sup>n</sup>). However, we do have that

> b<sup>n</sup> = 2<sup>(lg b) n</sup> = 2<sup>O(n)</sup>

because (lg b) n = O(n), since (lg b) is just a constant factor.

It is definitely a bit weird that O(2<sup>n</sup>) is not the same 2<sup>O(n)</sup>. The idea of using big-O notation in exponents is somewhat odd the first time you see it (for example, [n<sup>O(1)</sup> means "something bounded by a polynomial"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506562/why-does-no1-mean-polynomial-time)), but you'll get used to it with practice.